# How to add GIF file in Xcode assets foler?

Tags: xcode, xcasset

I'm using Xcode 12.4 and I want to use GIF image in my app.

So I put GIF Image in Assets.xcassets folder.

But UIImage can't recognize the GIF file with this error message

```
CoreUI: attempting to lookup a named image 'imgname' with a type that is not a data type in the AssetCatalog
```

[image]

When I open Assets.xcassets folder in xcode, the file is represented like above image.

How to solve this error? I use code to get image

```
UIImage.animatedImage(with: [UIImage(named: "img_name")!], duration: 15.0)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the image file in question?

Comment: Sorry I can't post the gif image because it is product of company:(

Answer (score 0):

That's because `UIImage is not support file in data set`.

You must use `NSDataAsset` to load gif data from `data set`